# How to plot histogram in R from data?

Tags: r, graph, statistics, histogram

```
Interval    Occupancy Rate
18:35:00    100%
18:40:00    100%
18:45:00    100%
18:50:00    100%
18:55:00    99.78%
19:00:00    100%
```

Hi all, I would like to plot a histogram where x-axis is the time interval and y-axis is the occupancy. How am I suppose to do with the hist() code as I've tried basic hist and ggplot2, but it seems like histogram gives y-axis as freq often. Is there any way to do this or I should use another stats graphic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't you mixing up [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) and [bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that D is the name of the data frame, and Interval and Occupancy are the names of the columns, as Pascal suggested above, you need a bar plot to visualize the data the way you indicated. It depends whether your Interval variable is already in a date format, in such a case you won't need a conversion of the variable. Otherwise, you need to use as.Date() to convert the data as shown below. You also need to convert the percentage occupancy values to numeric as shown below in the code I used to produce the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
Interval <- as.Date(c(18:35:00, 18:40:00, 18:45:00, 18:50:00, 18:55:00, 19:00:00), format = "%H:%M:%S") 
Occupancy <- c("100%", "100%", "100%", "100%", "98.78%" ,"100%") 
D <- data.frame(Interval, Occupancy)
D$Occupancy <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", D$Occupancy))
qplot(Interval, Occupancy, data=D, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

Hope this was helpfull

Comment: The interval data should ideally be converted to a time representation via `as.POSIXct` or similar, otherwise it will not plot at the appropriate point on the x-axis.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for answering. But i have the data above was part of my sample, i have larger data in R. Can i do like D$Interval for x-axis and D$occupancy for y-axis. given the dfrm is "D"

Comment: @SiewmeiLoh Use the `data` argument of `qplot` to feed the function with your data.frame.

Comment: @SiewmeiLoh I have modified the code above considering the comments above. It worked for me fine in RStudio.

Comment: @S.Elzwawi hmm my y-axis appeared to be weird. it started from 100% and 99%, 98% as it goes up. X-axis works well!

Comment: @SiewmeiLoh Maybe you need to convert your Occupancy variable to numeric.